# Spark Dataframe partitions querying from Hbase using Phoenix

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, hbase

I would like to understand how distribute work well during a reading from a very big `HBase` table using Apache Spark Dataframe. My questions are:

- Is there a possibility to set the **initial partitioning** when attempt to perform the reading?
- If not, **how is choose the partitions number**?
- Any **hint for optimize dataframe** reading query?
- I had a little problem creating the query with both **SQL API** and **Dataframe API**, basically, this is my code:

---

```
    sqlContext
          .read
          .format("org.apache.phoenix.spark")
          .options(Map("table" -> tableName, "zkUrl" -> zookeperHostPort))
          .load()
          .where($"YM" === measureYyyymm)
          .where($"D".isin(measureDd:_*))
          .filter($"REC_ID".startsWith("MG-") or $"REC_ID".startsWith("MP-"))
          .repartition(totalCoresNumber,$"POD")
```

These calls are translated by the Catalyst into:

```
SELECT * FROM LP WHERE ( YM = '201703' AND D = '03' AND REC_ID LIKE 'MG-%' OR REC_ID LIKE 'MP-%');
```

Actually **predicates push down** should involve the **WHERE** clause and thus just YM and D fields and not REC_ID. And if REC_ID was involved this is done in the wrong way because from the code written should be:

```
SELECT * FROM LP WHERE ( YM = '201703' AND D = '03' AND (REC_ID LIKE 'MG-%' OR REC_ID LIKE 'MP-%'));
```

I solved it putting a repartition in the middle, like below:

```
sqlContext
              .read
              .format("org.apache.phoenix.spark")
              .options(Map("table" -> tableName, "zkUrl" -> zookeperHostPort))
              .load()
              .where($"YM" === measureYyyymm)
              .where($"D".isin(measureDd:_*))
              .repartition(totalCoresNumber,$"POD")
              .filter($"REC_ID".startsWith("MG-") or $"REC_ID".startsWith("MP-"))
```

Could someone explain that behaviour?

Regards